# How can I perform multiple Gradle tasks in Jenkins, or string multiple Gradle tasks?

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, groovy, build

I have a Jenkins build where "goals" (or tasks, in Gradle) are passed as an environment variable to my Jenkinsfile.

e.g. `sh "gradle ${GRADLE_TASKS}"` where `GRADLE_TASKS` has the value `"clean build"` will run `gradle clean build`.

This works very well until I get to sub-projects.

Let's say I have subprojects

```
root
|-- com.mycompany
|-- com.mycompany.api
\-- com.mycompany.ui
```

As far as I'm aware, if I want to run a clean build on just `com.mycompany.api` I'd need the command:

```
gradle :com.mycompany.api:clean :com.mycompany.api:build
```

My problem is that the passed variable may represent one (or many) tasks to run.`clean`, `build`, `clean build`, `deploy`, `clean deploy`, `clean publish deploy` etc.

> **Note:** I need to keep this to a solution that uses the Jenkinsfile (not the Gradle plugin, for example) because it is a hybrid build that doesn't only utilise Gradle.

My first instinct was to loop through the tasks (as below), but it seems Jenkins doesn't let you run loops like this.

```
def tasks = GRADLE_TASKS.split(' ')
tasks.each { task ->
    sh "gradle :com.mycompany.api:${task}"
}
```

How should I go about this?

[edit] I should have also specified, is there some way to run this nested, so that I can `clean` all subprojects and then `build`?

e.g. The equivalent of:

```
gradle :com.mycompany.api:clean :com.mycompany.ui:clean
gradle :com.mycompany.api:build :com.mycompany.ui:build
```

I *would* do it like this (below) but obviously Jenkins doesn't like groovy closures...

```
tasks.each { task ->
    subprojects.each {project -> 
      gradle :${project}:${task}
    }
}
```

Comment: `sh "gradle ${GRADLE_TASKS.split(' ').collect { ":com.mycompany.api:${it}" }.join(' ')}"`

Comment: @tim_yates Thanks very much! That's great. Worth noting that these closures seem to need triple-quotes if spread across multiple lines (your example doesn't, but worth knowing for people who try).
Is there an easy way this can be easily adapted to my new example in the question? A collection of projects that each need one task run and then another...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the answer provided by @tim_yates goes some way to answering the problem in a very 'groovy-like' manner.

```
sh "gradle ${GRADLE_TASKS.split(' ').collect { ":com.mycompany.api:${it}" }.join(' ')}"
```